# SQL Query to group and add time between consecutive rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Need help with SQL Query (MySQL)

Say I have a table with data as..

[image]

The table has the Latitude and Longitude locations logged for a person at some time intervals (TIME column), And DISTANCE_TRAVELLED column has the distance traveled from its previous record.

If i want to know how many minutes a person was not moving (i.e DISTANCE_TRAVEKLLED <= 0.001)
what query should i use?

Can we also group the data by Date? Basically i want to know how many minutes the person was idle in a specific day.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the previous time for each record.  I like to do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.time
        from table t2
        where t2.device = t.device and t2.time < t.time
        order by time desc
        limit 1
       ) as prevtime
from table t;
```

Now you can get the number of minutes not moved, as something like:

```
select t.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, prevftime, time) as minutes
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.time
              from table t2
              where t2.device = t.device and t2.time < t.time
              order by time desc
              limit 1
             ) as prevtime
      from table t
     ) t
```

The rest of what you request is just adding the appropriate `where` clause or `group by` clause.  For instance:

```
select device, date(time), sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, prevftime, time)) as minutes
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.time
              from table t2
              where t2.device = t.device and t2.time < t.time
              order by time desc
              limit 1
             ) as prevtime
      from table t
     ) t
 where distance_travelled <= 0.001
group by device, date(time)
```

EDIT:

For performance, create an index on `table(device, time)`.

Comment: Sorry, but the query takes for ever to execute.. I even tried for just 10 records.. Going into some kind of infinite loop..